# Showing non-monotonicity (and unimodality) of particular function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to show that
$$f(x) = \mu \frac{e^{r(x - \mu)}}{s^2 + e^{r(x - \mu)}} + x \frac{s^2}{s^2 + e^{r(x - \mu)}}$$
where $x > \mu > 0 $, $s^2 > 0$ and $r > 0$ is non-monotonic or, even better, unimodal with respect to the distance between $x$ and $\mu$. More precisely, that the function at first increases as $x$ grows, but that the marginal effect eventually becomes negative.

The approach I have taken is to show that the marginal effect $\frac{df}{dx}$ can be both positive and negative. First, taking the derivative with respect to $x$ we get

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{s^2 e^{r \mu}(s^2e^{r\mu} + \mu re^{rx} + e^{rx} - rxe^{rx})}{(s^2e^{r \mu} + e^{rx})^2}. $$

Since the denominator is never negative, the sign of the derivative only depends on the difference 
$$s^2e^{r\mu} + \mu re^{rx} + e^{rx} - rxe^{rx}.$$

First, the derivative must initially be positive. To show this, I set $x = \mu$ (implying no distance between $x$ and $\mu$) yielding

$$s^2e^{r \mu} + e^{r \mu} > 0.$$

However, I am bit unsure about how to prove that the derivative eventually will become negative. Rewriting the above expression, we get

$$\frac{s^2 e^{r \mu}}{e^{rx}} + r \mu + 1 - rx.$$

As $x$ grows, the first term will decrease in size, the two middle terms are constant and the third term increases in size. But how do I show that it will for sure be negative at some point? Is it enough to show that the marginal effect tends to 0 as $x \rightarrow \infty$ since it is a continuous function?

Many thanks,

Comment: What is known about the parameter $r$? In some contexts the word *unimodal* is used to describe a function that increases to a unique "peak" and thereafter decreases.  This might help improve your Question, since you are interested in showing more than merely the function is *not* monotonic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification question! I should have added that $r > 0$. And showing that it is unimodal would be even better than merely showing that it is not monotonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last expression can be written as

$$s^2e^{r(\mu-x)} + r(\mu-x) + 1$$

and if $\mu$ is constant then as $x\to\infty$ the expression goes to $-\infty$.

---

Let $t = \mu - x$, and notice that $x > \mu > 0$ implies $t < 0$.
The derivative equals $0$ if and only if

$$s^2e^{rt} + rt + 1 = 0.$$

When $t\to0$, the expression approaches $s^2 + 1 > 0$.
On the other hand, because $s^2, r > 0$ the expression is easily seen to be monotonically strictly increasing on $t$.

It follows that, as $t$ decreases along the negative axis, the expression too strictly decreases monotonically, and hence it equals $0$ for a single value of $t$ and then becomes negative for all values afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. This is probably the easiest way. Do you have any suggestions to show that it is unimodal?

Comment: Check the edit.